# I can't remove broken MongoDB

Tags: dpkg, uninstall, 21.10, mongodb

When I run the command

> sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
> v

**I got this errors**

> E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-server_5.0.6-2_amd64.deb E:
> Couldn't find any package by glob
> 'mongodb-org-server_5.0.6-2_amd64.deb' E: Couldn't find any package by
> regex 'mongodb-org-server_5.0.6-2_amd64.deb'

And when I run `service mongod status`  this is the result

> ○ mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mongod; generated)
> Active: inactive (dead)
> Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

I don't have mongodb files in `var/log/mongodb`  and `/var/lib/mongodb`

Comment: Hello. Did you not ask this exact same question a few hours ago?

Comment: I just verified you asked the exact same question yesterday. Please do not ask the same thing over and over . If you have new info edit the first question to add it.

Comment: **DO NOT** create duplicate posts, use only one question for the same thing.  Answer questions asked of you in the comments on the original post as well.